# Python and signal handlers

Tags: python, signals, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

I am in need for some clarification regarding signal handlers in python, as I do not precisely understand how they work, how I can use them and what the limitations are.

I intend to use USR signals on linux in order to communicate with a python program running in the background as a service.

I found that, as intended, the signals I send seem to be processed immediately in an asynchronous way.

Therefore, I used to think that the registered signal handlers run in their own threads which, I thought, would explain why the following code will print multiple lines of `Signal handler called with signal 10` at once when sending signals in a loop

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
# This is the file signal_example.py

import signal, time, os

def handler(signum, frame):
    print('Signal handler called with signal', signum)
    time.sleep(20)

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler)

time.sleep(100)


#!/usr/bin/bash
for ((i=0;i<100;i=i+1)); do 
    killall -s SIGUSR1 signal_example.py; 
done
```

However, documentation states (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/signal.html) "Python signal handlers are always executed in the main Python thread, even if the signal was received in another thread.". Also, I do not see separate threads running on my system for the above example.

I am now wondering, what the actual implications and limitations of my approach to using signals are and how I can properly do relevant things such as communication between instances of the invoked signal handlers.

For example, in certain cases, I would like to be able to delay the execution of some code inside a signal handler until previous signals of the same kind have been processed.
Also I do not understand how many signals will be processed "in parallel" and what happens when the "queue" is full ...

I have been looking a bit into Pyhton's `asyncio`, which seems to offer some control of asynchronous code, and also brings its own way to register signal handlers. It seems to offer some aids, however, it does not seem to help me a lot since the behavior that I see (signals beeing handled pretty much when they are received) is actually what I want. The use of `asyncio` signal handlers that I have seen appears to execute the signals in the event loop. In the partially blocking code that I am starting with, that could be too late. I could run some of it in separate threads (using the corresponding `asyncio` functions), but not make the entire code non-blocking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I intend to use USR signals on linux in order to communicate with a python program running in the background as a service.

That sounds like a really bad idea. Here are several reasons why:

- Unix signals are delivered asynchronously, which means you can get a signal while any library code is running, such as in the middle of a `malloc` call. For this reason, only a small number of functions are [async-signal-safe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html), i.e. safe to invoke from a signal handler. Python code cannot execute inside a signal handler at all, so the handler set by `signal.signal` doesn't execute the Python function, but simply sets  a global flag. This flag is checked by the main thread from time to time, which executes the Python handler function. This means that there is no guarantee that the signal will be delivered immediately, i.e. you cannot rely on the signal delivery guarantees provided by the operating system.
- A signal may arrive during the execution of a handler of a previous signal. This is why you are seeing multiple lines being printed, it is the artifact of the signal handler itself being interrupted by a signal and reentering.
- Unless you set up signal handlers using specialized POSIX calls (and handlers set up using those calls can't directly execute Python code), signals will not be queued. Even when they are queued, except for non-real-time signals, the order of signals between generation and delivery is not preserved.
- Signals interact really badly with multi-threaded code, even in pure C.

If you have a service that you need to communicate with, you could have a thread that reads from a named pipe or listens on a socket. Writing to the pipe, or opening the socket, would serve as a signal to the process. This also allows passing additional information to the service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The picture that I get from your description is that the binary code generated from my Python script contains explicit checks for that signal flag. I am assuming that the signal handler would not interrupt the `malloc` (you seem to refer to UNIX there), but potentially between atomic Python instructions. The reception of a signal does not stop the running signal handlers, but it can interfer with them and the main program flow. An obvious question to ask is if it makes sense to consider starting a new thread manually in each of my signal handlers.

Comment: If you have, could you point me to a reference where pipes or sockets are used for inter-process communication with a python script?

Comment: @highsciguy A signal handler would definitely interrupt `malloc` - the alternative would be for each `malloc` to block signals and restore them, which would require two roundtrips to the kernel and impact performance. But you don't care about that in Python because (as discussed in the answer) Python doesn't run your code directly off the handler.

Comment: Perhaps I still don't understand. I have been thinking that you mean to say that the UNIX-signal handler (low-level) would interrupt `malloc`, but the invoked Python handler function would run only when `malloc` is done (as soon as it sees that the signal handler flag is set). I would assume that with the first effect of a signal `malloc` would need to cope since it is a standard UNIX-think that many processes implement.

Comment: @highsciguy That is what I mean to say, yes. The point is that the signal handlers registered in Python will run later than those registered in C. In other words, if raw speed of delivery is the motivation for using signals, you won't see it in Python.

Comment: My motivation for the signals is that they are handled asynchronously. Of course I don't get anything close to real-time. At least the signals are handled quicker than `asyncio` with my partially blocking code. In a replacement based on pipes I would need to have that code in a separate thread.